# iOS app crashes while trying to install Codepush update and also update rollback happens

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, code-push, react-native-code-push

"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-code-push": "^5.2.1",
using appcenter-cli
iOS version: 13.1.3

I code pushed a new version of the app, made it mandatory and the JSbundle is getting downloaded whereas its not getting installed. https://codepush.azurewebsites.net/updateCheck?deploymentKey=XXXX&appVersion=YY&packageHash=XXX&isCompanion=&label=&clientUniqueId=XYXYXY

I am able to see the latest update value in the label. Whereas when the app is trying to install, it just crashes and the new update never gets installed. I see as soon as the app crashes the build rollback also happens.

I checked my iOS profile and certificate they haven't expired. The build doesn't have any crashes too.
In code push I am checking for update on app resume. It was working all fine till yesterday.